# Создать словарь из списка слов: ключ слово -> значение его индекс в списке

Tags: python

Застопорилась в задании на курсе Python. Основная задача - сравнение предложений. Я остановилась на этапе 3 задачи:

1. Каждая строка в файле соответствует одному предложению. Считайте их, приведите каждую к нижнему регистру с помощью строковой функции `lower()`.
2. Произведите токенизацию, то есть разбиение текстов на слова. Для этого можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением, которое считает разделителем любой символ, не являющийся буквой: `re.split('[^a-z]', t)`. Не забудьте удалить пустые слова после разделения.
3. Составьте список всех слов, встречающихся в предложениях. Сопоставьте каждому слову индекс от нуля до `(d - 1)`, где `d` — число различных слов в предложениях. Для этого удобно воспользоваться структурой `dict`.

Проблема в том, что я не могу в упор сделать вот это: "Составьте список всех слов, встречающихся в предложениях. Сопоставьте каждому слову индекс от нуля до `(d - 1)`, где `d` — число различных слов в предложениях. Для этого удобно воспользоваться структурой `dict`."  Я остановилась на коде ниже, и да, он выдает мне списки со всеми словами, пустые строки убраны, но как перейти к dict, я не могу осознать.

Код:

```
import re
for line in open("sentences.txt"):
 s = line
 y = s.lower()
 text = re.split('[^a-z]',y)
 lines = list(filter(bool, map(str.rstrip, text)))
```

Comment: Добавьте описание того, в чём конкретно у Вас проблема.

Comment: Мне кажется лучше так разделить слова `re.split('\W+', y)`. По идее, если **можно** воспользоваться, то можно и не воспользоваться.

Comment: Да, так тоже отлично работает )

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы превратить **list** в **dict** можно использовать функцию **zip**
Пример:

```
>>> key_lst = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
>>> value_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(key_lst, value_lst))
>>> my_dict
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

Если я правильно понял в text хранится список слов.
Избавимся от повторений:

```
>>> text = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'eggs', 'bar']  
>>> words = list(set(text))
>>> words
['eggs', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Далее сошьем список чисел от 0 до len(words) и список слов words

```
>>> dict(zip(range(len(words)), words))
{0: 'eggs', 1: 'bar', 2: 'foo'}
```

Ну, как-то так... :)

P.S. Порядок слов при использовании list(set()), конечно теряется, но ведь в конце мы получаем dict. А в нем порядок и так нарушится.

Comment: set можно использовать, так как в вопросе нет требования в каком-либо порядке на индексы выбирать. Но объяснение про dict у вас в корне не верно: порядок ключей в dict не оказывает никакого влияния на хранимые значения. В виде упражнения, чтобы лучше понять задачу, напишите код, который индексы выставляет в порядке первого появления слов в тексте. Словарь для результата так же можно использовать (только индексы будут переставлены у слов).

Comment: Это не вся задача - потом мне потребуется сделать из получившегося словаря матрицу (текст в файле - предложения, каждое на новой строке), в которой i - число строк, j - число вхождений каждого слова в предложение. А потом сделать векторное сравнение, чтобы, наконец, определить, какое из данных предложений ближе всего к первому.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так можно перейти от list к dict:

```
In [1]: lines = ['one','two','three']
In [2]: dict((index, word) for index, word in enumerate(lines))
Out[2]: {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three'}
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: это ломается, если не все слова уникальны: *"d — число различных слов в предложениях"* Вызовите `unique_words = set(map(str.casefold, all_words))` и переставьте `word <-> index`: `{word: index for index, word in enumerate(unique_words)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(text)
```